# Android development in Unreal with an existing project

Tags: android, unreal

I am currently using an Unreal 3 project that has been targeted for multiple devices.  Originally, it was targeted for iOS and now I want to try and build it for Android. The project is capable of doing it and I am in the process of testing it.

I think I have everything I need in order to build it and launch it for an android device that I have set up and connected to my PC and is recognized by the Android SDK ABD. I am currently trying to build and launch the game through the Unreal Frontend but when I try, I am getting stuck at getting the Unreal Frontend to find my Android device as a platform to debug, like it would with a PC, Xbox360, or PS3.

Right now, I am just trying to launch the game to see if I can get it to simply run on an Android device, I'm going to worry about the packaging later.

So I have two questions:

Am I on the right track in looking at the Unreal Frontend to cook and launch the project on Android or should I look somewhere else?

How do I get Unreal to recognize my Android device as a platform to launch on?  I would even settle for recognizing an emulator, but that seems even harder.

Answer (score 1):

Following up to my own issue.  Turns out it was the limitations that were put on me that were the downfall of this feature.

In order to make Unreal Frontend recognize an Android device, at least in this situation, the UDK must be installed along with the project.

I was working on the project without the UDK with no issues except for this one. Once it was installed, it worked out.